# Why did the dialogue in skyrim change languages?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I recently purchased and downloaded the DLC Hearthfire for my PS3 Skyrim game. I started playing it, everything was fine and everyone in the game spoke English to me... Until I clicked on them, asked them a question then they talk to me in French for some reason?! As soon as I end the conversation the language goes back to English.

Comment: Might sound a little stupid but have you tried language options just in case...

Answer (score -1):

Check the language options to see if it has the DLC in French. You might have to play the DLc while in French.

Comment: @ user78194 Wait this answer doesn't answer the question my mistake all right!